# Static block on results.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently using Magento version 1.7.0.2 and having some issues with blocks and them displaying correctly.

I've got a "popularhome" static block that I display on my homepage cms page that works fine using the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('popularhome')->toHtml(); ?>
```

However if I add this to the cataglosearch>results.phtml it returns no products available am I missing something here to you need to re-define the block somewhere for the results.phtml page? This works 100% fine on the home page of the magento store to pull through 4 products in the correct layout.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Your code looks right. Are you sure the template catalogsearch/results.phtml is available? On mine it's result.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

I think file should be `result.phtml` and it is located in `app/design/frontend/{PACKAGE}/{THEME}/template/catalogsearch/`

You can check again by adding that block in this file.

I hope this this will be useful.